# Python webbrowser - Open a url without https://

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-webbrowser

I am trying to get python to open a website URL. This code works.

```
import webbrowser
url = 'http://www.example.com/'
webbrowser.open(url)
```

I have noticed that python will only open the URL is it has `https://` at the beginning.

Is it possible to get python to open the URL if it's in any of the formats in the examples below?

```
url = 'http://www.example.com/'
url = 'https://example.com/'
url = 'www.example.com/'
url = 'example.com/'
```

The URLs will be pulled from outside sources so I can't change what data i receive.

I have looked at the python docs, and can't find the answer on stackoverflow.

Comment: This works on my machine with `http://www.example.org`.  Maybe close your open browsers and try again?

Comment: why can't you change the url if you pull it from an outside source? It's quite easy to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add it?

```
if not url.startswith('http')
    if url.startswith('www'):
        url = "http://" + url
    else
        url = "http://www." + url
```

Comment: @ThomasWagenaar The first if statement will work for both.

Comment: aww yeah forget that, nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to change the url string (which is quite fast and easy) like [stazima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4920579/stazima) said, then you can use Python 3. It supports all the listed url types in your question (tested them).